# Изменение интервалов opacity в javascript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

1. Подскажите, как сделать, что бы опасити сначала (6 раз) менялся со скорость 250 мс, потом (13 раз) 1000 мс, а потом текст и вовсе становился статичным.
2. И возможно ли это потом зациклить, что бы через определенный период опасити снова начинал меняться 6 раз, 13 раз и вновь статичным и т.д.

```js
var i = 0;

function interval() {
  blink.style.opacity = 1 - (blink.style.opacity || 1);
  i++
  if (i < 6) {
    setInterval(interval, 250)
  } else if (i > 7) {
    setInterval(interval, 1000)
  } else(i = 20) {
    clearInterval(intervalID)
  }
}
var intervalID = setInterval(interval, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="blink">Привет, мир</div>
```

Comment: А вы понимаете что в итоге у вас это все дело умрет?) учитывая что каждую секунду будет создаваться новый интервал, который в свою очередь будет создавать еще один интервал и пытаться получить доступ к одному свойству. Но я так полагаю, код и не предполагался быть "правильным" - он для идеи.

Comment: А насчет вопроса - да это вполне возможно. Просто вам нужно немного переделать способ, которым вы управляется интервалом. В вашем случае нужно управлять intervalID выставляя ему другую скорость срабатывания при соблюдении условия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;
var timer, intervalID;

function interval() {
  blink.style.opacity = 1 - (blink.style.opacity || 1);
  i++;
  if (i === 6) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    intervalID = setInterval(interval, 100);
  }
  if (i === 19) {
    // тут мы останавливаем выполнение - делаем статическим
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    console.log("stopped");
    timer = setTimeout(initInterval, 5000); //Ждем 5 секунд и запускаем заного
    console.log(timer)
    i = 0;
  }
}

function initInterval() {
  console.log("init");
  intervalID = setInterval(interval, 250);
}

initInterval();
```

```html
<div id="blink">Привет, мир</div>
```

Как-то вот так получилось у меня. Разумеется, можно и покрасивей сделать. Но вроде понятным способом расписал.

Есть еще способ (через рекурсивный setTimeout). Но он менее понятный:

```js
var i = 0;
var currentInterval;

function interval2(prevInterval) {
  blink.style.opacity = 1 - (blink.style.opacity || 1);
  if (i <= 1)
    return 250;
  if (i === 6) {
    return 1000;
  }
  if (i === 19) {
    // тут мы останавливаем выполнение - делаем статическим текст
    // ставим время "ожидания"
    console.log("stopped");
    i = 0;
    return 5000;
  }
  return prevInterval;
}

function runSetTimeout(){
    console.log("Started recursive");
    setTimeout(function run() {
      i++;
      currentInterval = interval2(currentInterval);
      console.log(currentInterval);
      setTimeout(run, currentInterval);
    }, 250);
}
runSetTimeout();
```

```html
<div id="blink">Привет, мир</div>
```